# Best way to recursively include python Tornado templates

Tags: python, html, templates, tornado

I've in my python project, using the tornado library:

1) A main html template (the web page structure), like:

*base.html*:

```
 <html>
 <head>....</head>
 <style>...</style>

 <div id="content">
 {{ sub_template_content }}
 </div>
</html>
```

2) multiple sub-templates, one for each page, like:

*page1.html*:

```
<b>page 1 {{ content }}</b>
```

*page2.html*:

```
<b>page 2 {{ content }}</b>
```

The idea is to always build the page using the "base" template and then include the "sub-template" dynamically (based on the get parameter).

So, what's the best way to do that? I already tried using the tornado "include" function, but without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `extends`/`block` feature instead.  In base.html:

```
<div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% end %}
</div>
```

In page1.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    page 1 {{ content }}
{% end %}
```